# The userid get from web login and app login is the same?

Tags: facebook-login

The facebook login have mang types: web login,android login and ios login. All of them can get a userid. My question is: when people login with the same facebook account, can get the same userid? even login in different login type.

Answer (score 0):

User IDs are scoped by App, so they would get the same ID.